# Check if text field is empty before executing jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This might be a very easy question, but I find it confusing.

How do I run myFunc() if `textField_1` is not empty?

Excicute `.on('click', '#openButton', myFunc)` if `($('#textField_1').val()!="")` ?

Comment: what's the definition of `myFunc`?

Comment: I agree, most jQuery is excruciating.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check inside the handler:

```
.on('click', '#openButton', function() {
    if( !$('#textField_1').val().trim().length ) myFunc(); //thanks to @Mike for the suggestion on trim and length, see comments
})
```

Comment: @Mike -- Always open to suggestions.

Comment: User trim, that way we're ensuring that it isn't a useless string. Also, you don't need to check if val != "", the length property is easier to check (it will be a boolean test without having to compare strings)

Comment: if(!$('#textField_1').val().trim().length) myFunc();

Comment: Np, that's what SO is for, improving all of our code :)

Answer (score 0):

Refer below code

```
 <div>
     <div>
         <input type="text" id="text"/>
         <input type="button" value="click" id="click"/>
     </div>
 </div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#click").click(function () {
        if ($("#text").val() != '') {
            myfunction();
        }
    });
 });
 function myfunction() {
    alert($("#text").val());
 }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test `$('#textField_1').val()` in an `if` statement. If it's empty, it'll be treated as `false`, otherwise it's treated as `true`.

JS (jQuery):

```
$('#openButton').on('click', function () {
    if ($('#textField_1').val()) {
        myFunc();
    }
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/flowstoneknight/vadn28da/).